# Cannot convert type <class 'pyspark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint'> into Vector while using StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib

I am using SaprkStreaming to train a simple StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD model with PySpark. Firstly, I was trying to simulate the random inputStream for model(fixed Vector w dots random Vector x, then plus random value obeying GuassianDistribution),code like below:

```python
import sys
import socket
import time
import random
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce

def return_random_guass_seq(_type=list, len_term=10, mu=0, sigma=1, _scale=1):
    return _type([_scale*random.gauss(mu, sigma) for i in range(len_term)])

# set w vector
len_term = 100
w = return_random_guass_seq(_type=np.array, _scale=10, len_term=len_term)

socket_server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket_server.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
socket_server.bind((sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2])))
socket_server.listen(5)

while True:
    conn, (ip, port) = socket_server.accept()
    print(ip, port)
    while True:
        random_sleep_time = random.random()
        noisy = random.gauss(0, 1)*5
        x = return_random_guass_seq(_type=np.array, len_term=len_term)
        y = x.dot(w) + noisy
        time.sleep(random_sleep_time)
        s = str(y) + reduce(lambda i, j:str(i)+','+str(j), x, '') 
        print(s)
        conn.send(bytes(s, 'utf-8'))
        conn.send(bytes('\n', 'utf-8'))
    socket_server.close()
```

Then, I initialized StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD model and tried to trainOn labeledStream,

```python
import sys
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
from pyspark.mllib.regression import StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD
import numpy as np

#initialize sc,then initialize ssc
sc = SparkContext(appName="StreamingModel")
#just print ssc result and error 
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

ssc = StreamingContext(sc, batchDuration=5)# 5 seconds window 
stream = ssc.socketTextStream(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]))

#create model 
len_term = 100
Model = StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD(stepSize=0.1, numIterations=50)
Model.setInitialWeights(np.array([0.0, ]*len_term))

# create actions
labeledStream = stream.map(
    lambda x:tuple(x.split(','))
    ).map(
    lambda x:(float(x[0]), np.array([float(i) for i in x[1:]]) )
    ).map(
    lambda x:LabeledPoint(label=x[0], features=x[1])
    )

labeledStream.pprint()
Model.trainOn(labeledStream)
Model.predictOn(labeledStream).pprint()

# start sc_stream
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

And ran into the following error

`TypeError: Cannot convert type <class 'pyspark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint'> into Vector`.

I can't figure out why this error happened. Was I misunderstanding something apperent or it was the result of negeligence?

Full trace:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zh/spark_hadoop/hadoop/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/zh/appcache/application_1512094491627_0072/container_1512094491627_0072_01_000003/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 177, in main
    process()
  File "/home/zh/spark_hadoop/hadoop/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/zh/appcache/application_1512094491627_0072/container_1512094491627_0072_01_000003/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/home/zh/spark_hadoop/hadoop/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/zh/appcache/application_1512094491627_0072/container_1512094491627_0072_01_000003/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 268, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/home/zh/spark_hadoop/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/regression.py", line 746, in <lambda>
  File "/home/zh/spark_hadoop/hadoop/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/zh/appcache/application_1512094491627_0072/container_1512094491627_0072_01_000003/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/regression.py", line 121, in predict
    x = _convert_to_vector(x)
  File "/home/zh/spark_hadoop/hadoop/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/zh/appcache/application_1512094491627_0072/container_1512094491627_0072_01_000003/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/linalg/__init__.py", line 83, in _convert_to_vector
    raise TypeError("Cannot convert type %s into Vector" % type(l))
TypeError: Cannot convert type <class 'pyspark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint'> into Vector

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 0):

`StreamingLinearAlgorithm.predictOn` requires `DStream[Vector]`. You have to `map`:

```
Model.predictOn(labeledStream.map(lambda x.features)).pprint()
```